# rules for android UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I 'm having problems with my android UI.  My buttons dont align properly. Even though i have my button aligned to right, but still wont line up correctly?

I was wondering is there any document that would explain how to layout things correctly and how would widgets behave when they are inside a tablerow? Or in other terms how does hierarchy affect the way things are aligned??
Thanks

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="?screenBackground">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="?pageBackground">
            <TableRow>
                <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
                    android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_gravity="left"></ImageView>
                <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="@string/button1"
                    style="?button"></Button>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why don't you take a look at the API demos that come with the SDK?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to illustrate the issues you're having?

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

For example, you could align your `ImageView` and `Button` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_width="60dip" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To get a feel for what is possible, the starter docs on `RelativeLayout` are [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Comment: that does not solve my problem.. I have many more widgets that need to be added to this screen. That is why i m looking for some kinda document that would tell me the rules to follow while coding :)

Comment: That's why I linked you to those two android dev docs pages that have hints on RelativeLayout. Those will give you other examples of using RelativeLayout besides the one I posted.

Comment: Relativelayout really is the way to go with this. If you're new to android layouts, I highly recommend checking out the Hello, Views tutorials over at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html.